# PHP Test for Malformed Database

Tags: php, python, sqlite, error-handling

I have a Python script that uploads a Database file to my website every 5 minutes. My website lets the user query the Database using PHP.

If a user tries to run a query while the database is being uploaded, they will get an error message

> PHP Warning:  SQLite3::prepare(): Unable to prepare statement: 11, database disk image is malformed in XXX on line 127

where line 127 is just the `prepare` function

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE page_url_match = :pageurlmatch");
```

Is there a way to test for this and retry the users request once the database is done uploading?

Comment: What about enable exceptions and use `try-catch` block?

Comment: you should upload the file with a different name and then copy/move it to the correct name when finished thus avoiding down time during the upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to upload a database to separate `%DBNAME%_temp` and after upload is finished just drop old one and rename the new one to `%DBNAME%`.

But if this is not an option you can try specify throwing exception on any error via `$options` array while creating PDO object.

```
new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
])
```

And then just use `try { ... } catch` to catch this warning and rerun user query.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily related to PHP but I ended up modifying the Python code to upload the file with a temp name and then rename

```
import ftplib
FTP.storbinary("STOR " + UPLOAD_FILE_NAME + ".bak", myfile) 
FTP.rename(UPLOAD_FILE_NAME + ".bak", UPLOAD_FILE_NAME)
```

Comment: Yes it is a sqlite db